# Dynamic Pulldown reading data from Json File

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am having difficulty in getting this functionality running correctly.
Here is my html for this simple form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta name="" content="">
<script type="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/outils.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
      <select id="County">
      <option value="0">Select County Please</option>
      <option value="ANTRIM">ANTRIM</option>
      <option value="ARMAGH">ARMAGH</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Town"></select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is my jquery which is found in a file named outils.js in the js folder.

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
var tabCounty=[];
$.getJSON('county.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
        tabCounty[index]=val;
    }); 
});

$('#County').change(function(event) {
    $county=$(this).val();
    $htmlOption='<option value="0">Select County Please</option>';
    if($county!=0)
    {
        $.each(tabCounty[$county], function(key, value){
             $htmlOption+='<option 
value="'+value[0]+'">'+value[1]+'</option>';
        }); 
    }
    $('#Town').html($htmlOption);
});
});
```

And finally below is my json file name county.json which is placed in the js folder.

```
{
"ANTRIM":[
["1","AHOGHILL"],
["2","ALDERGROVE"],
["3","ANDERSONSTOWN"],
["4","ANTRIM"],
["5","ARDDOYNE"]
],
"ARMAGH":[
["1","AGHACOMMON"],
["2","AGHALEE"],
["3","ALLISTRAGH"],
["4","ALTNAMACKEN"],
["5","ANNAGHMORE"],
["6","ARMAGH"]
]
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Dave

Comment: What functionality are you trying to get running? If you check the console do you see any errors?

Comment: when i select the county in the first pull down the second pull down is populated with corresponding towns found in the json file